Attaching non edible item to a cake?
Hoping this makes sense… I am making a cake for my daughter and she wants printed images of theater playbills. I formatted what I need into 2x3” images, printed on a heavy cardstock and then mounted on a glitter construction paper (the kind that doesn’t spew glitter everywhere). My dilemma is how to place that paper on the cake - I mean, they won’t be eating it but I’m hesitant to just place a piece of construction paper on the cake. I was thinking mounting it to a piece of rice paper or those icing sheets but then how to attach to those? Just a dab of frosting as “glue”?

If you're trying to have them stick up, you could just attach it to popsicle sticks or wood skewers and use those to stab them into the cake... just make sure they come out before kids try eating them

If you have time you can get images printed onto edible paper and sent to you.

I did as @GdD suggests, with 2 full pages of my thesis.  Turnaround was only a few days. That looked pretty good, and the paper was fairly stiff

@ChrisH \documentclass{cake}?

Maybe glue it to a wax paper backing?

You are totally right, if you want to put the playbill flat against the cake then a barrier of some sort between the cardstock and the icing makes sense. Although you could put the paper right on the icing there could possibly be some sort of flavor transfer which you'd want to avoid. Plus, glitter construction paper will still drop a bit of glitter, so you want to keep that off the cake as well.
I would do exactly as you say: use baking paper, rice paper or some other food friendly material as a barrier, and couple blobs of frosting to attach it.
If you want to stand it up instead you could glue long coffee stirs or skewers to the back of the card as @Joe suggests in comments. I wouldn't use toothpicks as they aren't long enough, and are likely to fall over. You could print another copy of the playbill and glue it to the back of the other one with the skewers hidden in between so it would look good from either side.
In many places there are edible printing services which will color print your images onto edible paper (essentially a very thick starch/sugar paste) and mail them to you. It takes some time but it's actually pretty cool looking.

My big custom print was on rice paper, and I've had smaller ones as well
